# How to convert an enum from another enum into a string

Tags: java, enums

I have a pair of related enums in Java.

Enum Alphabet

```
{
  A, B, C;
}
```

Enum Phonetic

```
{
  Alpha (Alphabet.A, Amber)
  Bravo (Alphabet.B, Beta)
  Charlie (Alphabet.C, Cookie)
}
```

How do I convert the Alphabet.A values in enum phonetic into a string?

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: It is in Java..

Comment: It'd depend on what you want the string representation to be. Most enum constants iirc simply defer to `Enum#name`. So `Pheontic` would output `Alpha`, `Bravo`, etc. Alphabet would `#toString` as `A`, `B`, `C` etc. I would also question the usage for this, as the design might have a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two sets of enums that have equivalent values stored in the same order, then you can use the ordinal value from one to look up the equivalent value from the other.

```
int ord=Alphabet.A.ordinal();
Phonetic equiv=Phonetic.values()[ord];
System.out.println(equiv);
```